# How to insert decimal point and round using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Data set is from https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial, number 9

I am using

```
SELECT name, ROUND(population, 3,0), ROUND(GDP, 3,0)
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'South America'
```

Answer should be

```
name        
Argentina   42.67   477.03
Bolivia 10.03   27.04
Brazil  202.79  2254.11
```

I am getting

```
name        
Argentina   42669500    477028000000
Bolivia 10027254    27035000000
Brazil  202794000   2254109000000
```

...

Comment: Don't forget to divide the numbers with a million/billion.

Comment: Hi Chris, what is the value stored in the bd for GDP? I have the feeling that you just need to divide by 100000000 before rounding. Do have insight on the source system and how the GDP is transformed before being in the table?

Comment: @Cid, 42.67 millions.

Comment: Hi @chrisfinn, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not  forget to comment the answers you get for your question. You can accept the answer if they are correct. It would be nice to get your feedback... Cheers!

Comment: Some side notes: You forgot to paste `GROUP BY name` and possibly `ORDER BY name`. Without the `GROUP BY` the query would be invalid of course. The table name `world` is misleading, as the table doesn't contain worlds, but countries. Its name should be `country` or `countries` hence. And it is advisable to have another table `continent` so the country table would only contain a continent ID referencing a row in the continent table. With your current design, you could have typos leading to wrong query results.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, check the link provided in the question, sqlzoo alone is responsible... (On the other hand, OP did chose sqlzoo.)

Comment: @jarlh: Oh, right, I skipped the first line when reading the request :-) Anyway, as chris finn is using a tutorial for learning SQL obviously, pointing out the flaws in that tutorial may help him understand databases better :-)

Answer (score 2):

You want the population in millions and GDP in billions, both rounded to two decimals. Consider:

```
SELECT name, ROUND(population/1000000, 2), ROUND(GDP/1000000000, 2)
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'South America'
```